# How to implement multiple nodes of multidimensional arrays in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have to implement A* Algorithm (http://heyes-jones.com/astar.php) to solve 15-Puzzle game in C++. I would  have an initial state of my board, e.g:

```
01 02 03 04

05 06 07 08 

09 10 11 00

13 14 15 16
```

Later on I also need to save its next all possible states in new node with some other information like heuristic cost of the board, number of moves have been taken yet etc. 
My total number of nodes could go upto 4 million as i have board of size 4x4.
I have some suggestion to used priority queues for this purpose. Could any body suggest me more proper way. I also would need to compare all the previous nodes to compare with newest one to avoid the same node to add again. Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two fundamental data representations for this puzzle.

The first is to save the state of the board in each node.

Another representation is to save the move in each node.
The graph of the traversal describes the moves made.  The board state can be calculated.

There is no proper way.  Choose a way and get it working correctly.

Comment: I would have open states and closed states. I have plan to put open states in Priority Queues and closed states in Hash tables but the problem is that the sum of opened and closed chains could upto 4 million in count in worst case if there is no solution and it would take a lot of memory. For each state I would need an array of 4x4 size and I also need to save the number of moves taken yet into data structure. How to manage the memory?